# Microcontroller to interface with Led Driver

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, led, .net-gadgeteer

My knowledge of Micro-controllers is fairly limited at this point, but here goes.

I have an Led Driver PT6959 which I'm trying to interface with. Data is read serially by the Driver IC on the input CLK rising edge once the STB input line goes low.

My question is, how do I know what the input CLK frequency should be?

Does it matter? Or should it be the same as the Led Driver OSC Pin frequency?

I've read the datasheet but can't find any reference to specifying an input CLK frequency.

Comment: the datasheet or other documentation for that device will have either a max frequency (and maybe minimum) and/or will have a minimum time period (which you invert and get frequency).

Comment: Okay I see there is nothing in the datasheet...Just have to try it and see, maybe they expect it can outrun any microcontroller.  I take that back different datasheet shows the timing for PWclk,  Wont post that here since all the other items from that same drawing are relevant to what you are doing

Comment: Would it work so long as the CLK frequency is always less than OSC frequency

Comment: doesnt matter, you should always look at the chip vendors documentation and conform to it. or have a good reason for not (guaranteed temperature, etc).

Comment: Ok, so PWclk full width comes in at 800ns, so whatever that is as a frequency would be my answer, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your microcontroller has a SPI port, connect as follows:

```
DIN <-- SPI-MOSI
CLK <-- SPI-CLK
STB <-- CS (often just a GPIO rather than a dedicated SPI chipselect)
```

The SPI peripheral will then do most of the work for you.  Most SPI peripherals allow different combinations of polarity and phase known as *modes*:

```
Mode  CPOL  CPHA
0     0     0
1     0     1
2     1     0
3     1     1
```

The PT6959 operates in mode 3.

The clock rate is probably not be critical.  If you are bit-banging it rather than using SPI, it need not even be periodic or fixed - it is the state of DIN on rising and falling edges that is critical - not the frequency.  The device will have some maximum rate - the data sheet specifies this in terms of minimum mark/space widths of >=400ns, assuming a 50% mark:space, that would correspond to 1.25MHz, but there is little benefit in operating at the maximum speed.

Answer (score 3):

I have found it finally [here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.princeton.com.tw%2FLinkClick.aspx%3Ffileticket%3DUTU7GOM8tHk%253D%26tabid%3D474%26portalid%3D0%26mid%3D888%26language%3Dzh-CN%26forcedownload%3Dtrue&ei=igyuU6OtNIKulAX4ooGoAw&usg=AFQjCNEpMqzlhT_dIiXqFSIEKJ1X9awKQQ&sig2=3I96SEVctZQ7kzihToBc5Q&bvm=bv.69837884,d.dGI) the bigger datasheet fourteen (14) pages, not three.

So the time constraints for this signal as below,

```
PW CLK (Clock Pulse Width) ≥ 400ns
t setup (Data Setup Time) ≥ 100ns
t CLK-STB (Clock - Strobe Time) ≥ 1μs
t TZH (Rise Time) ≤ 1μs
t TZL < 1μs
V1.7
PW STB (Strobe Pulse Width) ≥ 1μs
t hold (Data Hold Time) ≥ 100ns
t THZ (Fall Time) ≤ 10μ
fosc=Oscillation Frequency
t TLZ < 10μs
```

As you can see the minimum clock pulse can be as 400ns which means the maximum clock frequency can found as 1/(2x400x10<sup>-9</sup>) = 1250000Hz (1.25Mhz)

Other calculations you can do the same way. But, yes, it is everything needed better covered at time-diagrams, which are given in the document above. I place them here just in case the link can die one day.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: While that is a reproduction of the data sheet, it is not an *answer*.  You might put some interpretation on it.  In fact the timing diagram is more critical - the clock need not be a fixed frequency as @chillydk147 seems to think.

Comment: @Clifford I added some calculation and explanation to the answer. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: And my point is ALL of the numbers on that page are important not just the max frequency you can clock.  PWstb, tclk-stb, tsetup, thold, etc.  Sure the question is strictly what is the max frequency...and that is 1/800ns.